# How to re-build deployed ASP.net website?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications

I'm connected to a customer's site. There is a bug in an ASP.net MVC site i'm trying to solve.

As i make changes in the various `.cs` files, the web-server is not changing it's behavior. It seems that the web-site is determined to use the pre-compiled `.dll` files in the `Bin` folder.

How can i instruct IIS to recompile the web-site from scratch, in order to pick up the live changes?

I tried deleting my own `.dll` file:

```
\Bin\Contoso.dll
```

But then the web-site crashes.

**Note**: i am asking how to do this without access to Visual Studio; otherwise i would have changed the web-application into a web-site and redeployed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to recompile the dll with your changes from your development machine and deploy them. MVC ( I mean asp.net application)  uses dll not source code. In short , what you are asking is not possible.